# Array slice does not return the remaining items

Tags: javascript

As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), if the `end` parameter in `Array.slice(start, end)` is greater than the length of the sequence, it will extract through the end of the sequence:

> If end is greater than the length of the sequence, slice extracts through to the end of the sequence (arr.length).

I have the following code:

```js
const a = new Array(30).fill(5)

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 25) {
    const newItems = a.slice(i, 25);
    console.log(newItems)
}
```

I get the following output:

```sh
> (25) [5, 5, 5, ... 23 items more]
> []
```

I am expecting the second array to be of length 5 with the remaining 5 items being captured but I get an empty array. I am not sure why though because `a.slice(25, 25)` should give me items that start at index 25 up to the end of the array (since it's length is less than 25). Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Those are indices, not count - you are slicing from 25 to 25 (excluding)

Comment: slice with two given arguments slices the array from index of first parameter to index of second parameter. check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: `arr.slice(start, start + step)`

Comment: @ASDFGerte Ah, my bad. I knew it was something stupid. If you'd go ahead and provide this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Someone already provided an answer, so i won't need to type one, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `begin` and `end` symbolise indexes of the array in the documentation. `start` is inclusive, but `end` is exclusive, so you are trying to retrieve slice for the following range: `[25, 25)` that is an empty set from the mathematical point of view.

Your code should look like this:

```
const a = new Array(30).fill(5)

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 25) {
    const newItems = a.slice(i, i + 25);
    console.log(newItems)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The start and end argument for the slice function indicate the index positions in the array. Start inclusive and end excluded. The code you have is trying to use 25 as start and end. Hence the empty array maybe trying adding a count might give you your intended output.

```js
const a = new Array(30).fill(5)

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 25) {
    const newItems = a.slice(i, i + 25);
    console.log(newItems)
}
```